# Gaps in HTML emails in Outlook 2013

Tags: html-email, gaps-in-visuals

I'm having an issue with gaps appearing in Outlook / windows in an html email which I can't fix. It's a common problem I know and possibly something to do with col spans (judging by other posts). I've tried a number of things to do with line heights (although height doesn't appear to be the issue here) and adding ms specific styling but to no avail.

You can see the code here:
http://www.theindustryclub.co.uk/xmas/ticChristmasTemplate_card.html

and see the problem here
http://www.theindustryclub.co.uk/xmas/images/industryClubMailing.jpg

It's looking tight in all other clients and web based mail apps - just pesky outlook 2013 dragging me down and got me stumped. I would be grateful for any suggestions / help.

Martin

Comment: Thx DCC - I knew it was something to do with darn colspans - I've zapped them and replaced with nested tables and we're up and running

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all your images are inline styled `display:block;`
2. Don't use colspan or rowspan.. use nested tables instead.
3. Set `table, table td { border-collapse:collapse }` in the head
4. Check your cellpadding values to see if they are pushing the content out.

[Here's a template you may find useful.](https://github.com/dcondrey/html-email-boilerplate)